# Serialize multiple text files using boost C++

Tags: c++, vector, serialization, boost, text-files

Is it possible to serialize multiple text files using boost? As of now, I have a system in place to read a text file in normally as seen below:

```cpp
std::ifstream readFile(afile);

while (afile) // While reading file
{
    getline(afile, input); // Reads file, stores it in input. 
    vecTest.push_back(input); // Gets words from input and stores them in vector. 
}
readFile.close();
```

This will read the file and store the contents into a vector. To serialise the contents of the vector, I use this next piece of code:

```cpp
std::ofstream readFile("serialise.txt");
boost::archive::text_oarchive archiveFile(readFile);

archiveFile << vecTest;
readFile.close();
```

How could I set it up to add additional text files once these are loaded?

Comment: You can have a *vector of vectors*.

Comment: How do you define "serialize multiple text files"? Aren't the files, by definition, already serialized?

Comment: I'm trying to attempt to read a text file to a vector, serialize it, then restore it. However, I need to do this 3 times at the same time which is the issue.

Comment: How "at the same time"ish do you want this? If you thread it, the threads will probably start fighting over access to the disk and wind up slower.

Comment: If "at the same time" merely means "without writing the same code three times[,]" I think you're looking for a function.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archives are structured streams. They already organize different objects serialized to the same archive.

So here you could easily just:

```
using File = std::vector<std::string>;
File f1{100, "file 1 line"},
     f2{200, "file 2 line"},
     f3{300, "file 3 line"};

{
    std::ofstream ofs("ondisk.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << f1 << f2 << f3;
}
```

And then, we could check:

```
f1.clear(); // oh no...
f2.clear(); // looks like we
f3.clear(); // forgot the data

{
    std::ifstream ifs("ondisk.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> f1 >> f2 >> f3;
}

std::cout << "Remembered " << f1.size() << "/" << f2.size() << "/" << f3.size() << " lines\n";
```

Which prints (**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64df8f839af69321)**):

```
Remembered 100/200/300 lines
```